# SEO not indexing my site: "A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt – learn more."

Tags: seo, robots.txt

When googling my site I get following text under the result for my domain:

> "A description for this result is not available because of this site's
>   robots.txt – learn more."

My robots.txt, which resides in the root of my V-host, looks like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

I did have a problem with this file before since I forgot to change it from the test environment and then I had

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

However, I did change it yesterday or the day before.

I have been googling and this seems to be a correct way of handling it as it is now.

Checking the access log of httpd for today, I can see that google has tried to it. But the access_log also shows that Googlebot has been accessing the most of my links as well, feels like ok indexing... Nothing in the error_log from today about robots.txt.

What I cannot find is if google has been indexing /index.php. But I guess folling entry is the same, isn't it?:

> 66.249.75.179 - - [07/Feb/2013:15:23:01 +0100] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 1 "http://www.mydomain.ext/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1;
>   +http://www.google.com/bot.html)

What is my problem and how to I resolve it?

**UPDATE**

When testing in Googles Webmaster Tool I get (this is for my .com domain, all above as well):

> Blocked by line 2: Disallow: / Detected as a directory; specific files
>   may have different restrictions

And when doing the exact same thing with my .se domain, which points to the exact same content, I get:

Allowed by line 2: Disallow:
Detected as a directory; specific files may have different restrictions

Comment: Patience... Google's internal processes aren't very fast. Give it a day or two.

Comment: Don't create more than one SE account. Use the same account to update/edit your posts. If you create a question on one account and then abandon that account for another one, how are you going to mark an answer as correct?

Answer (score 4):

Providing your robots.txt is as you say, like:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

Then based on the fact that you updated it ~12 - 48 hours ago then it could take a while longer before Googlebot reads the updated copy. As far as I'm aware, Google cache the robots.txt file for up to 24 hours (sometimes longer).

If you have a Webmaster Tools account it's probably worth checking the domain for any errors. For more reading check [Google's Crawler FAQ](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/faq#h18)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually update my post with info about the Webmaster Tools info while you posted your answer. I will check out the FAQ.